# Sums of uncountably many real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-analysis

Suppose $S$ is an uncountable set, and $f$ is a function from $S$ to the positive real numbers. Define the sum of $f$ over $S$ to be the supremum of $\sum_{x \in N} f(x)$ as $N$ ranges over all countable subsets of $S$. Is it possible to choose $S$ and $f$ so that the sum is finite? If so, please exhibit such $S$ and $f$.

Comment: There has to be something eluding me, why did you tag your question with the large cardinals and set theory tags?

Does the following argument not work? $S=\Cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace} S_n$ where $S_n=\lbrace s\in S\mathrm{~s.t.~} f(s)>\frac{1}{n}\rbrace$, thus one of them is non denumerable and taking a denumerable subset of said $S_{n_0}$ will yield an infinite sum.


Comment: I changed the tags.  The question is certainly not about large cardinals, nor even about set theory as that is understood on this site. 

Comment: Even though you already have your answer, I'm going to close since this particular question isn't quite what we want here.  Also, it is phrased in a style suspiciously resembling a homework problem.

Comment: It looks like something from Concrete Mathematics (Knuth, et.al.).
Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.05.10

Comment: Yes. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be constant at zero. But there are other cases I'm sure you could come up with by examining the answers here.

Comment: ...[end saracsm]

Comment: @David Roberts: the identically $0$ function does not fit the conditions imposed by the OP.  (Maybe that's part of your joke; if so, okay, but I didn't get it...)

Answer (score 16):

No.  $S$ is the union of the countably many sets $A_n=\{s\in S:f(s)>1/n\}$, so some $A_n$ must be infinite (in fact uncountable).  Thus, your sum contains infinitely many terms all of which are at least $1/n$.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I just realized how to solve the problem. The answer is that it is not possible.

Suppose the sum is finite. Let $S_n$, for positive integer $n$, be the set of $x \in S$ such that $f(x) \ge \frac{1}{n}$. Then for each $n$, $S_n$ must be finite, if the sum is finite. But $S = \bigcup_n S_n$, meaning that $S$ is at most countable.

In other words, the sum of uncountably-many non-negative real numbers is finite only if all but countably many of those real numbers are $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard result in undergraduate analysis, although it is admittedly somewhat hard to find in the standard references.  The following is a very non-standard reference: see the last exercise in II.9.4 of [these notes on sequences and series](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3100supp.pdf) (see p. 69...for now; page numbers are subject to change).  They occur in the context of a larger discussion on unordered summation, which is what you are looking into above.  The general definition of unordered summability is a bit more complicated (it is a nice special case of convergence with respect to a net, although one needn't use the term), but in the case where the values of the "$S$-indexed sequence" are non-negative, it coincides with what you have given: see Proposition 82.

Note that this fact comes up sometimes in practice.  In [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/is-there-a-function-with-a-removable-discontinuity-at-every-point) I set as a challenge to give a proof of the following fact -- there is no function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with a removable discontinuity at every point -- which *does not use* the kind of **uncountable pigeonhole principle argument** that you need to answer the current question.  And I got a very nice answer!